# Dealing with possible copyright violations or plagiarism?

Tags: discussion

I have noticed that a lot of questions and answers include images and quotes without attribution.  In many instances images are used that aren't licensed for reüse<sup>1</sup>.  In some instances I have found large blocks of text copied-and-pasted without it being quoted or clearly attributed<sup>2</sup>; this is typically considered to be plagiarism.  I've been going through and making at least some attempt at fixing these and gently reminded people to provide proper attribution.  It does feels like a game of whack-a-mole at times though.  How should this be handled?

<sup>1</sup> In some instances (e.g. a single diagram from a paper) this may well be covered by [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) provided the images are attributed.  [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/33136/27793) is a good example of proper fair-use usage (IMO).

<sup>2</sup> The [initial version](https://space.stackexchange.com/revisions/33116/1) of one answer for example.  Initially I honestly thought that it was original writing.  It wasn't until several hours later that I discovered that it was almost entirely a quote from an article.

Comment: @uhoh Regarding your just-deleted comment, I will likely post another question along the lines of "Can I include other people's images or text in my questions and answers?"  The answers could provide guidelines, best practices, etc.

Comment: While there is variation in style, most users here do take the time to add a simple [Source]() notation or a more detailed citation, some people under time constraints or using "primitive devices" may feel pressured to skip it, then forget to fix it later. Still, in some cases I suspect people do in fact just ignore citing the source altogether. This is wrong and should be called out each and every time. I think a well-written answer here can serve as a way to call it out in the future, providing the user good instructions how to do it, and why they really need to do so.

Comment: This question is about users behavior here so it's good to ask here. For your "another question" you might first check the main meta site. That's probably addressed fairly well for all of SE there.

Comment: @uhoh I poked around the other day and didn't see anything there.  I'll take another look though.

Comment: [1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64005/303080), [2](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185934/303080), [3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/240736/303080) just for example. If you have something unique, then you should definitely ask it. It's up to u if u ask here or in main meta. One of my questions here got migrated to main meta and did well. [Why is the changing-link-color scheme so subtle for beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/308453/303080)

Comment: Don't know how I missed those.  Thanks!

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240769/444105) looks about spot on.  From that answer: [What to do when plagiarism is discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160071/what-to-do-when-plagiarism-is-discovered) and [How to reference material written by others](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Please flag whenever you find these, even if you take action. It helps keep track of patterns of behavior.

Comment: @called2voyage Flag as in "Needs moderator intervention"?  Or flag as in leave a comment?

Comment: @AlexHajnal Flag as in need moderator intervention.

Comment: @called2voyage Shall I edit this question to note/request that?

Comment: @AlexHajnal No, I just meant to use the flag feature when you see what you describe in the question.

Comment: @called2voyage OK